# Three-way join in Entity Framework Core to retrieve all roles that a user has

Tags: c#, beginner, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm very new to Entity Framework Core, so I'm concerned about whether I've done this query in the most efficient way possible.

The database I'm querying looks like this:

[image]

Basically, `UserRoles` is a a "linking table" between the `User` and the `Roles` in order to create a one-to-many relationship. If a user exists at all, they will always have at least one role, but they could have several roles.

I want to get the role name based on the NT ID of the user.

This is something I plan to do fairly often, so I separated it out into a separate utility (rather than having it in the controller).

In SQL, I'd just do two `inner join`s. However, what I did here is to query `UserRoles` (rather than using `Join`).

```
public class UserUtilities
{
    public static List<Roles> GetRoles(string ntid)
    {
        var ctx = new MyLiveDocsContext();
        List<Roles> roles =
            (from ur in ctx.UserRoles
             where ur.User.Ntid == ntid
             select ur.Role).ToList();

        return roles;
    }
}
```

Ive tested this and it does what I want, but I'm wondering if this is the best way to do this. For example, would it be better to use an explicit `join` instead?

Comment: Did you check what SQL queries are produced by this code?

Comment: Also note: ["The lifetime of the context begins when the instance is created and ends when the instance is either disposed or garbage-collected. Use `using` if you want all the resources that the context controls to be disposed at the end of the block."](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/working-with-dbcontext)

Comment: @BCdotWEB Is the new title better?

Answer (score 2):

For this isolated piece of code, this is the way to go. Generally, in ORMs that support LINQ, navigation properties (like `ur.Roles`) should be used wherever possible. Using`join` should be reserved for custom joins where no navigation properties exist.

Reasons:

1. Joins are far more verbose than navigation properties, making code harder to read and causing repetitive code.
2. Joins are error-prone. It's easy to match the wrong fields. A navigation property, once configured correctly, will always generate a correct SQL join.
3. Navigation properties, if well-named, are more expressive. In a `join` the cardinality of a relationship isn't always obvious. In navigation properties it is. You know what you're looking at when reading `Role` vs `Roles`. Unfortunately, sometimes people tend to be sloppy in this area and they just use the generated class and property names as an ORM generated them, which may result in any mixture of plural class names, plural reference property names, and singular collection property names.

One exception to this rule is when you want to overrule the ORM's SQL generation. Entity Framework will generate an `OUTER JOIN` for non-required navigation properties (i.e. where the "1"-side is optional, 0..1-n, 0..1-1). There may be cases where `INNER JOIN` performs better and the results with `null` navigation properties aren't interesting anyway. In those cases, using a manual `join`, overriding a navigation property, could be considered.

Side note: as said in a comment, it's recommended to use disposable objects, like a `DbContext`, in a [`using` statement](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement).